# From float tensor to double tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm building a convolutional neural network in python. To get the convolucional layer I try to do this:

```
def convLayer(x, kHeight, kWidth, strideX, strideY,
              featureNum, name, padding = "SAME", groups = 1):
    """convolution"""
channel = int(X_train_tf.get_shape()[-1])
conv = lambda a, b: tf.nn.conv2d(a, b, strides = [1, strideY, strideX, 1], padding = padding)

conv.double()

with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(name) as scope:
        w =  tf.compat.v1.get_variable("w", shape = [kHeight, kWidth, int(channel/groups), featureNum])
        b =  tf.compat.v1.get_variable("b", shape = [featureNum])
        
        xNew = tf.split(value = X_train_tf, num_or_size_splits = groups, axis = 3)
        wNew = tf.split(value = w, num_or_size_splits = groups, axis = 3)
    
        featureMap = [conv(t1, t2) for t1, t2 in zip(xNew, wNew)]
        mergeFeatureMap = tf.concat(axis = 3, values = featureMap)
         print mergeFeatureMap.shape
        out = tf.nn.bias_add(mergeFeatureMap, b)
return tf.nn.relu(tf.reshape(out, mergeFeatureMap.get_shape().as_list()), name = scope.name)
```

The problem is with featureMap = [conv(t1, t2) for t1, t2 in zip(xNew, wNew)]

because conv expected a double tensor and got a float tensor. I tried to change t1 and t2 ( I called x and y) with:

```
        for x, y in zip(xNew, wNew):
            x.DoubleTensor()
            (x,y)= torch.from_numpy(x,y).double()
            y = torch.from_numpy(y).double()
            x,y=x.type(torch.DoubleTensor),y.type(torch.DoubleTensor)
```

But any part of that code works. the most comon error is

'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object has no attribute 'type'/'double''... etc.

Someone has a solution for that? Thanks.

Comment: Please specify the line where you got the error .

Comment: You should avoid using tf.compat.v1 it can introduce bugs and it is useless for recent versions of tf

Comment: the error is in the line 16 "featureMap = [conv(t1, t2) for t1, t2 in zip(xNew, wNew)]"
the problem is the arguments of conv.

I found teh using of  tf.compat.v1 to work with get_variable because it didint complile without tf.compat.v1.